# NTP Time display at every second

Tags: ntp

I want to receive time at every one second interval from the NTP server and display it in a GUI. As I know that minimum poll interval for NTP request is greater than one second.

How can I get every one second time.

Comment: If you have a computer with a clock capable of knowing exactly 1 second has passed to do the next request, why would you need to ask an NTP server the time again a second later?

Comment: What system are you working with where there is a measurable system clock error over 1 second?

Comment: Time synchronization is not as simple. Please do not down vote this.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to get time from a server every second ? This will muck up your server big time. Ideally you should get time once, and then get it only as often as it starts to drift. That is exactly what NTP does for you automatically. It has polling algorithm's to ensure that you use your clock as effectively as possible. Your clock is not as bad, even the worst ones basically drift 1 second in 24 years.

Ideally just show if NTP is "in sync" or is "still trying to figure out". For that use NTPQ.

I once developed NTP for Netware, so I understand the protocol in detail. It takes 2-3 minutes to sync the time. Since everytime you poll, the error margin is just too high. Think about it, if a client requests for time, the returned time can be as wrong as the amount of time it took to get that response back. That is exactly what NTP does. It calculates over time how much time it took for the network to respond to that time request. Its a lot of statistics in play here. DONT fool with it, instead DONT do what you are doing until NTPQ says that you are in sync.

**Edit**

Just setup NTP and let it do its job. If you care about accuracy of time upto milliseconds, then check for "is in sync", else just read time off your local server.

Comment: Hi sidharth thank u very much for Your answer. Actually i want to display GPS(UTC+16) time in My application which my computer can not display.So i want that whenever time format is changed in NTP server the same change be directly affected in my application. Thats why i want to receive time directly from the NTP server and display in application